# How did you get ASP.NET to output UTF-16 encoded text?

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, utf-16, ashx

How did you get ASP.NET to output UTF-16 encoded text?

I serialize an object in .NET which by default is UTF-16 format. Now I want to send the string as an output response to an .ashx request.

I get the error:
Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported. Error processing resource

How do I tell my website or page to use UTF-16 format.

Thanks.

**Update:** read both answers.

Comment: What is the exact line which throws the exception? Please, edit the question.

Comment: The XML Parser inside Internet Explorer was throwing up the error because of the encoding format. So I think technically it was breaking on the very first few characters of the output. See my 4th or 5th comment on the accepted answer for what I had to do to get it Xml Serialized to UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: don't.

Web pages as UTF-16 confuse many tools and make browsers behave in odd, unexpected ways. (Esp.: linked scripts, form submissions, proxies). UTF-16 can only be served safely as a binary object, so for web content stick to an encoding that is a superset of ASCII - the obvious choice being UTF-8.

The error you quote is generally what you get when you try to read an XML file whose <?xml encoding="..."?> prolog clashes with the real encoding of the file. None of the superset-of-ASCII encodings ever clash because 'xml encoding' is ASCII and represented the same in all of them, but if you've put encoding="utf-16" in an XML file that's not saved as UTF-16, or you've *not* put it in when it *is*, then the parser can't cope with the logical impossibility.

Comment: Actually I am using the ToXml Extension Method from here: http://solidcoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/c-toxml-extension-method.html .Since System.String is stored internally as UTF-16 that is where my problem is. I will have to use a longer ToXml method that accounts 4 this and converts to UTF-8

Comment: Perhaps XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream, Object) onto a byte stream, rather than (TextWriter, Object) is what's required?

Comment: @bobince, that is what the examples I saw online showed. Oh well few extra lines of code. thats all.

Comment: Not exactly how I wrote it, but close enough: http://blog.newslacker.net/2008/02/net-xml-serialization.html and I used UTF8

Comment: That example too is using the TextWriter. I haven't tried it, but it seems to me like the method accepting a Stream instead should be byte-oriented and hence not produce a spurious 'encoding="UTF-16"'.

Answer (score 2):

Change the [`Response.ContentEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding.aspx) property to [`System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
Dim utf16 = New UnicodeEncoding(False, True)
Response.BinaryWrite(utf16.GetPreamble)
Response.ContentEncoding = utf16
```

By the way, I needed to do this because I was sending an html table which contained unicode characters to Excel.  (I know, not the best way to create an Excel file!)

Excel (and LibreOffice Calc) expects utf-16 and doesn't work with utf-8.  Excel also needs the UTF16 BOM at the beginning, hence the call to GetPreamble.